# HTML5/Javascript SSE limit number of calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, server-sent-events

I'm fairly new to ServerSend Events using js and HTML5. I have a basic set up with my page calling an API, the API execute a command line, and I'm trying to display the result of this call in realtime (the api is calling a script on the server and i'm serving the console output).

My problem is that if the page stays open, the API keeps on getting called. I would like to stop this behavior and having the API called only once. I tried using a boolean to define the event source only once but with no luck.

Here is my js code:

```
function liveExec($scenarioId){
    var $run = true;
    if ($run)
    {
        var source = new EventSource('/run/'+$scenarioId+'/1');
        source.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
    };
    $run= false;
    }
}
```

The function is called with a button click. 
Here is my access Log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2016:11:09:06 +0200] "GET /run/1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2318
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2016:11:09:31 +0200] "GET /run/1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2318
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2016:11:09:56 +0200] "GET /run/1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2318
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2016:11:10:21 +0200] "GET /run/1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2318
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2016:11:10:47 +0200] "GET /run/1/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 2317
```

Visibly the function is called every 25 seconds for some reason.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about closing the connection by means of `source.close();` after running it for the first time?

Comment: This indeed seems like a possible way. From my research I can see that this is a feature of the browser trying to keep the connection alive with the server. So I either need to disable the auto-reconnect feature, or catch the end of the stream to manually close the connection client-side. Is there a way, an event, to do that ? Or do I need to send a specific message ?

Comment: Try using `eventSource.onerror = function(e) {
        if (this.readyState == EventSource.CONNECTING){this.readyState == EventSource.CONNECTING }` on the client side. When your connection is over your browser seems to attempt to recover it and in this case you can do your work

Comment: Sorry, there is a misprint in my last comment. I meant: eventSource.onerror = function(e) { if (this.readyState == EventSource.CONNECTING){ closing... } }

Comment: That helped! Thanks!

Comment: Why not send a retry:timeinmilliseconds ?